# Convert bigint to date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two dates I calculated as follow:

```
CASE WHEN FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 1 THEN  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , ManualDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) END AS M_ttp
CASE WHEN FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 0 and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 THEN  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , SystemDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) END AS A_ttp
```

I need to have the total amount of these two in Second and then calculate the AVG, but I get NULL when:

```
            (Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 1 and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 then  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , ManualDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) End +
            Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 0 and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 then  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , SystemDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) End ) As Total_TTP,
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You're probably missing an `ELSE 0` or two. `CASE WHEN x THEN ... END` is `NULL` when `x` is not true, and adding `NULL` to anything is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two contradicting cases inside that query and you are not handling case when condition is not met. Based on `mf.IncomingTocontrol` either first or second case will be NULL, and NULL+Anything is always NULL

You should either, put ELSE blocks in each CASE:

```
(
 Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 1 and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 
 then  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , ManualDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) 
 ELSE 0 End 
 +
 Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 0 and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 
 then  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , SystemDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) 
 ELSE 0 End 
) As Total_TTP,
```

or use COALESCE to wrap for value if NULL

```
(
 COALESCE(Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 1 and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 
 then  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , ManualDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) End, 0) 
 +
 COALESCE(Case When FinalApprovalDt is not null and mf.IncomingTocontrol = 0 and ContractPayoutAmt > 0 
 then  DATEDIFF ( SECOND , SystemDecisionDt , lastChangesByAgentDt) End, 0)
) As Total_TTP,
```